# Crash when trying to reorder cell in collectionview (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a ViewController and inside of it, I have a UICollectionView.
I have upgraded my iOS target because it was previously 8.0 but to be able to reorder cells in a collectionview, the iOS 9.0 is mandatory.

So now, i have first added this code :

```
extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //blablabla
    }
}
```

But the function is not called when I long press on a cell and move it.
So then, I have seen that we need to add this code, if the collectionview is in a ViewController.

So I have added :

```
func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
switch(gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collView)) else {
                break
            }
            collView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            collView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(self.collView))

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            collView.endInteractiveMovement()

        default:
            collView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
}
```

But now my application just crash !!!
Actually, when I long press on a cell then try to move it, the function "updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition" is called, and in Xcode it just crash without any error message.

Is there a parameter I have forgotten to set, or something else ?

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Is the viewController assigned to the collectionView's delegate? `self.yourCollectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: Yes. And I have already implemented other function on this collectionview as  "didSelectItemAtIndexPath", without any problems.

Comment: Check out this guide might help you : http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/  Also , make sure when you include the crash error logs make it easier to know what your error is.

Comment: I just found the error by adding exception breakpoint. Actually, in the collectionview function "sizeForItemAtIndexPath", I refreshed the layout of my view with "self.view.layoutIfNeeded()". I hope it's clear :), but now it works ! Thanks !!

Comment: Have same problem on iOS 10 + Objective C. Crash happens on starting moving collection view item on line [self.collectionView updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view]]; where do you call layoutIfNeed ? seems it does not help